# Why do stabilizer cut the Hilbert space into two halves?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, stabilizer-state

I am trying to follow the logic of Slide 8 in [this deck](https://www.appi.keio.ac.jp/Itoh_group/spintronics/pdf/QC2005/QI-School-2005-12.pdf).

The result is that if you have $n-k$ stabilizers in the set of stabilizers, then the dimension of the +1 eigenspace of all the stabilizers is $2^k$.

The intuition in the slides is that each stabilizer has an equal number of +1 and -1 eigenvalues since each stabilizer is a Pauli operator. So indeed, it cuts the Hilbert space into two halves of equal dimension.

But why is it that if you have two different stabilizers, say $S_1, S_2$, they cut the space in two exactly four quarters? If one thinks of it geometrically, it's not clear why the "lines of the cut" must be orthogonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take independent stabilizers $S_1,S_2,\dots$.

First, note that $\mathrm{tr}(S_i)=0$, as well as $\mathrm{tr}(S_i S_j)=0$, and the same for any other product of the $S_i$ (as those all are  Pauli products with at least one non-identity).

This means that $S_1$ has half +1 and half -1 eigenvalues. Thus, taking its +1 eigenspace cuts the space in half.

Next, note that $P_1=(I+S_1)/2$ is the projector onto that space. Then,
$$
\mathrm{tr}(P_1S_2)=(\mathrm{tr}(S_2)+\mathrm{tr}(S_1S_2))/2=0\ .
$$
That is,
$S_2$, when restricted to the $+1$ eigenspace $P_1$ of $S_1$, has half +1 and half -1 eigenvalues. Projecting onto the +1 space thus again cuts the space in half.

You can continue like that.

Answer (score 6):

More carefully, if you have $n$ qubits and $n-k$ *linearly independent* stabilisers, +1 eigenspace has dimension $2^k$.

The way that I like to think about this is that each stabiliser yields $\pm 1$ values. So, not only is there the space where all the stabilisers have $+1$ value, but also the spaces where the stabilisers take on the different values $\{\pm 1\}^{n-k}$. Now, I assert that each of these spaces is the same size, and so it must be that the space is of size $2^n/2^{n-k}=2^k$.

Why do I assert that? Take the space where all the stabilisers are $+1$, and take the set of all Pauli operators that commute with the stabilisers. This set is often denoted $N(S)$ for the normalizer. Now, consider some $\sigma$ which gives a particular syndrome (set of stabiliser values). If $\tau\in N(S)$ then because $\tau$ commutes with all the stabilisers, it is also true that $\sigma\tau$ has the same error syndrome as $\sigma$ did. In other words, for every element of $N(S)$, there is a counterpart in each of the different subspaces. So you can see that each of those spaces will be the same size.

Comment: Very nice argument, thank you. Does one also need to prove here that there exists a $\sigma$ for every choice of syndrome?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a two-line proof: Let $S$ be a stabilizer group of rank $n-k$. The projector onto its trivial representation (i.e. the joint +1 eigenspace) is $
 P = \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{\sigma \in S} \sigma $. But then, the dimension of this subspace is $\mathrm{tr} P = \frac{\mathrm{tr}\mathbb{1}}{|S|} =\frac{2^n}{2^{n-k}} = 2^k$.

Note: From a representation-theoretic point of view, the subspaces in DaftWullie's answer are exactly the isotypic components of $S$ for which a similar projection formula applies.